# How to make jenkins run integration tests only when deploying to UAT?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I'm using jenkins and I have a `staging > qa > uat > master environment set.` I don't want jenkins to run any integration tests in staging and qa environments, only for uat and master.

Is it possible to do that? If so, how? I mean, should I separate unit and integration tests in different packages? Today I have:

```
src/main/java

src/test/java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a interface IntegrationTest

```
    public interface IntegrationTest {}
```

And use the annotation `@Category` from Junit4 for categorizing your tests as integraiton test.

```
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class YourTest
```

So use the maven `surefire` and `failsafe` plugin to create groups of testes.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>you.package.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <groups>you.package.IntegrationTest</groups>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The Integration test will be automatically excluded from the default execution i.e mvn clean package. However, if you run `mvn integration-test` all the integration tests will run.

Comment: Hi Edu, thank you very much! Still need to test it though. As soon as I test it and it works, I select your answer.

Comment: @VandersonAssis if you are using JUnit5 then you can follow the instructions here: https://keyholesoftware.com/2018/02/12/disabling-filtering-tests-junit-5/